# How Spring Security configuration in xml file being trigger

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authentication, stripes

Good day,

I work on a web application that the spring security part was develop by senior developer.

I am trying to understand how its work, so for first step, I go to google "how spring security work", and I think I am looks like understand a bit, but actually not.

Lets take my application as example:

Here is some code of my `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Until this points, these part is looks similar with what I google.

Then I go for my security xml file (part of the code):

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/403_system.jsp" session-fixation-protection="newSession"
            entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" filters="none"/>
        ... other security in
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
        class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html" />
    <property name="forceHttps" value="${url.forceHttps}" />
    <property name="serverSideRedirect" value="${url.serverSideRedirect}" />
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextFilter" class="com.c.i.c.common.security.context.SecurityContextDetailsFilter">
    <security:custom-filter after="SESSION_CONTEXT_INTEGRATION_FILTER"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.cv.ibs.cib.common.security.filter.myWorkAuthenticationProcessFilter">
        <security:custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
   <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
   <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.html?error=1 "/>
   ...//some other property here
   <property name="exceptionResolver" ref="messageExceptionResolverService"/>
</bean>
```

And this is my form html code in my login.jsp

```
<form id="j_security_login" class="login" action="<c:url value='/j_security_login'/>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

I found that the `SecurityContextDetailsFilter` will run the `doFilterHttp()` method first, and then follow by `myWorkAuthenticationProcessFilter` `doFilterHttp()` method.

This is a bit different with what I read from internet. I am not sure why this 2 class trigger the `doFilterHttp()` method. Is it because of they extends `SpringSecurityFilter` class and `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` class, thats why they will trigger `doFilterHttp()` method when log in?

And I believe the `j_security_login` is a keyword to trigger the Spring Security logic. Am I right? So means that if I have a form submit to `j_security_login`, then it will go to see which class implement spring security class and `@Override` the `doFilterHttp()` method, then it will trigger the method.

Kindly advise.